# Import modules dynamically during Webpack compilation with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to create a framework for by hobby project where I have arbitrary amount of object definitions each in its own Typescript file. Then I have a factory, which creates entities based on these definitions when requested.

For example by calling `createEntity('Player')` the factory will use definition named `Player` to create a new entity.

As there could be a large amount of these definition files in the project I don't want to manually import all of them into the factory module. Since I'm using Webpack, I think it should be somehow possible to find all files which match a glob like `.entity.ts` and import them to the factory module **during compilation**. However, I'm not really sure how to do this.

I found several mentions about [context api](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#context-module-api) which seems to do what I need, but from the examples I saw I couldn't figure how to actually use it in my factory module. TSC also complains that it can't find the name `require` when I put the following lines in my module:

```
function importAll(r) {
  r.keys().forEach(r);
}
importAll(require.context('.', true, /\.entity\.ts/));
```

So how can I include all my definition files to the Webpack bundle and import them to my factory module without manually writing the imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a solution. First I had to install package `@types/webpack-env` and `@types/node` as dev dependencies.

Then the following code in my factory module picks and imports my definitions:

```js
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const knownEntities = importAll(require.context('../..', true, /\.entity\.ts$/));
```